# How can I change all commits of another user, "X" to another user, "Y"

Tags: git, git-commit, git-config

I am looking out for a way to change the commit histories on a project whereby the commit by user "X" is changed to commits made by user "Y".

Is that in any way possible?

The possible or similar solution I saw was this, `git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"`.

But it does seem to change the commits made by user "X" to user "Y".

Comment: You literally cannot *change* a commit. The method you described makes a new-and-improved *replacement* commit, kicking the previous commit off the end of the branch. All methods will involve this general concept (of making new-and-improved variants of the original commits).

Comment: In *some* cases, another way to approach the problem is to let commits as they are, but use a `.mailmap` to regroup some odd authors with their "main" name.